# One doubt on an NP hard problem

Tags: lattice-crypto

It seems that Shortest Vector Problem in a lattice  is NP hard. Then how Ajtai-Kumar-Sivakumar (AKS) algorithm solves it? I mean, what is the witness?

Comment: All problems may be solved, but you must pay attention to the complexity.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you linked to the algorithm in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, SVP is not known to be NP-complete. There are some hardness results for SVP, but just considering very specific scenarios (for instance, [SVP is NP-Hard in the $\ell_{\infty}$ norm](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397501002900/1-s2.0-S0304397501002900-main.pdf?_tid=bd881024-d4f9-11e7-a5ca-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1511955655_5cd87a34d23016fc5c8ff539ca152653)) or under other types of reductions (such as randomized or non-uniform reductions).

Even so, the [AKS algorithm runs in exponential time](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/svpalg.pdf), so, it doesn't give us any information about the hardness of SVP.

When we say that a problem is NP-hard, we expected that there is no polynomial-time algorithm to solve the problem, but there is nothing strange with the fact that we know exponential-time algorithms for the problem (and we usually know trivial exponential-time algorithms to solve hard problems...).

Comment: So under l_{infinity} norm SVP is not hard? Will you kindly  give a link?

Comment: No. It is actually NP-Hard in the $\ell_{\infty}$. Unfortunately, I didn't found a free-access paper demonstrating that fact, but it is a somehow well-known result. For instance, take a look at the third page of http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~inapprox/papers/SVP-micc.pdf  It talks a little bit about that and present some references to the original papers so you can find that result.

Comment: I have added a link to the hardness result of $SVP_\infty$. If that answers your question, please, accept it. If not, please, tell what is missing. Thanks.

Comment: SVP is indeed NP-hard and with $\ell_2$ norm. See the landmark paper of Ajtai,
*The shortest vector  problem in $L_2$ is NP-hard for randomized  reductions, 1998 *. For the norm $\ell_{\infty}$ is an old result of Emde Boas, proved in 1981. Randomized reductions (instead of Karp), means that if you solve SVP in $\ell_2$ norm, would allows us to provide a randomized algorithm for any problem in NP.

Comment: Hi @111. That is why I said in the answer that there were hardness results under randomized reductions. However, the usual definition of NP-hard does not involve randomized algorithms. Maybe there is a way to derandomize the reduction, but if it were trivial, I think that Ajtai would have talked about it on the paper.